# Angularjs: Assigning Array within object

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am having an issue with losing data within an array when i try to assign it to a new array.
My object im using is as follows:

```
$scope.shops = [
  {
    name: "Kroger",
    items: [ { itemName: "Chips"} ]
  }
];
```

This is the code for the functions im using, it may be a callback issue? or something?  Im losing the items info for the shop.

```
$scope.addItem = function(newItem, newShop){

    var x = findShop(newShop);
    x.items.push(newItem);
    $scope.shops.push(x);
};

findShop = function(shopTag){
    var old = angular.copy($scope.shops);
    var tar = {
            name: shopTag,
            items: []
        };
    $scope.shops = [];
    angular.forEach(old, function(shop, key){
        if(shop.name === shopTag) {
            tar.items = angular.copy(shop.items);
        }
        else {
            $scope.shops.push(shop);
        }
    });
    return tar;
};
```

the goal is to have the findShop function return a shop with the correct name, with empty items if there wasnt a shop previously, or with items full of the items if the shop was already created.  then the addItem will push the item into the shop.items array and push the shop into the $scope
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: oh, im sorry!!!  shopTag is a parameter to the function and contains the proposed shop name, so if it exists i want tar to contain all the items it previously had.

Answer (score 1):

You are right , it is this line which is causing the problem ,

tar.items = shop.items;

Try using it like this ,

tar.items = angular.copy(shop.items);

Comment: still losing the data,  i am relatively new to JS but maybe it is the function where the return goes to, like my callback is late?  let me edit

Answer (score 1):

```
var old = $scope.shops; // old and $scope.shops point to the same place
..........
$scope.shops = []; // you assigned a new array that overrides the data
............
angular.forEach(old, function(shop, key){ // for each on an empty array????
```

If you dont want to point to the same reference use:

```
var copiedObject = angular.copy(objToCopy);
```

Comment: i made the change and still seem to be getting the same results, its like the count for how many items is there, but the data is getting lost when i add them.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are trying to find a shop in your array then all you need to do is create a function which iterates through your collection and if the wanted item is found simply return it.

Comment: try something like this:
findShop = function(shopTag){
    angular.forEach($scope.shops, function(shop, key){
        if(shop.name === shopTag) {
 return shop.items;
        }
    });
    return null;
};

Comment: so, once i get the items from the shop already in the scope, how do i either splice the shop from the scope so i can take the items array, add the new item, and then push the "new" shop back out to the $scope.  or could there be a way to add the new item to the shop already in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the array is getting empty even before for loop.
Var old is reference to shops array, which you are making empty before foreach.. effectively making old empty...

Comment: ive seen this done countless times, where all the old shops are held in old and foreach itterates through old and pushes the shops that dont match back into the scope shops

Comment: Do console.log old, before foreach... is it not empty??